# How to retrieve the value from struts url tag and pass it to servlet

Tags: java

Hi I have a jsp with following code. The file has struts tag lib

```
<s:iterator value="TpData.vhp.actvh" var= "veh" status = "hellostatus">
        <tr>
           <s:url var = "ShowInfoAction" value="%{urlInfo.actionurl}" >
              <s:param name = "hereInfo" value="#someclass.method"/>
              <s:param name ="pincode" value="againsomeclass.pincode"/>
            </s:url>
         </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The param name ="hereInfo" has unique values. Since this is in iterator the url constructed will have different parameters. As this url is constructed in the jsp i want it to be passed on to action class. Is this possible?

Comment: Link parameters are available as request parameters. What specific issue are you having? And how do servlets come in to the picture if you're referencing an action?

Comment: sorry to the action class. I need these urls to be added in a Map.

Comment: is it possible to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a collection of similarly-named properties to be added to a map, use mapped param names, but the index is typed (e.g., Integer, String, etc.)

For example (from memory, but close):

```xml
<s:param name="hereInfo[%{hellostatus.index}]" value="#someclass.method"/>
```

Or a business-model ID etc., which would be more common.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I get this in the action class.

Comment: @TamilSelvi With a map property, like `Map<Long, String>` or whatever.

Comment: sorry my question was do I use something like request.getParameter to retrieve the url from jsp.

Comment: @TamilSelvi No, you expose a map property. Please consider reading some basic S2 documentation that covers how parameters work.